# PHP variable to be used in Javascript code for a game

Tags: javascript, php, bitcoin

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                 var oMain = new CMain({
                                win_occurrence:30,        //WIN    PERCENTAGE.SET A VALUE FROM 0 TO 100.
                                slot_cash: 2000000,          //THIS IS THE CURRENT SLOT CASH AMOUNT. THE GAME CHECKS IF THERE IS AVAILABLE CASH FOR WINNINGS. THIS SHOULD BE BALANCE OF MY OVERALL BTC ACCOUNT.
                                min_reel_loop:2,          //NUMBER OF REEL LOOPS BEFORE SLOT STOPS  
                                reel_delay: 6,            //NUMBER OF FRAMES TO DELAY THE REELS THAT START AFTER THE FIRST ONE
                                time_show_win:2000,       //DURATION IN MILLISECONDS OF THE WINNING COMBO SHOWING
                                time_show_all_wins: 2000, //DURATION IN MILLISECONDS OF ALL WINNING COMBO
                                money:<?php include 'getbtcbalance.php'; echo $btcbalance;?> ,               //STARING CREDIT FOR THE USER - THIS IS GOING TO BE AN ECHO OF USER ADDRESS BALANCE.. So 'getbalance of addressofsessionidvariable'
                                ad_show_counter:3
```

(after this isnt necessary to see as works fine)

As you can see, I am trying to get the 'money:' part to be a php variable called $btcbalance from the file getbtcbalance.php.

The php variable $btcbalance works fine on getbtcbalance.php and can be echoed to display the correct balance, I just need to make it work in the js script.

What I did above doesnt work, I just left it there so you can see what I'm trying to do.

Hope someone can help.

***EDIT:***

Attached as requested is the content of getbtcbalance.php:

```
<?php

    // Getting BTC address from database by using a post function 'selecting row of session username' 
//Set btc address as a ssession variable so that it can be used for topup
include_once 'blockconfig.php';
session_start();

$connect=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'PASSWORD') or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($connect, 'test6') or die("Cannot select database");

$sessionusername = $_SESSION['username'];
$res2 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM test WHERE username='$sessionusername'");
if (!$res2) {
printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connect));
exit();
}
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($res2);

$bitty = $row['btcaddress'];
$_SESSION['btcaddress'] = $bitty;
$btcbalancedetails = $block_io->get_address_balance($bitty);
$btcbalance = "".$btcbalancedetails->data->available_balance."";
// Do below if you need to echo the address on this page, or you can copy / paste it onto another page to echo the btc address

// if (isset($bitty)){

//   echo $sessionusername."'s BTC address for TOP-UP: ".$bitty;}
//    else { 
//            echo mysqli_error($connect);
// }


?>
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error on the console? is `$btcbalance` a string? if so then you need to surround it in quotes so that it is treated as such

Comment: Please share more information, like the source of the generated page (in the browser) or codes inside `getbtcbalance.php`. This question is a little unclear.

Comment: Please attach content of getbtcbalance.php file as well

Comment: Attached the relevant content :)

Answer (score 1):

You can include php file before html code then you use php file variable(s).

```
<?php include 'getbtcbalance.php';?>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                 var oMain = new CMain({
                                win_occurrence:30,        //WIN    PERCENTAGE.SET A VALUE FROM 0 TO 100.
                                slot_cash: 2000000,          //THIS IS THE CURRENT SLOT CASH AMOUNT. THE GAME CHECKS IF THERE IS AVAILABLE CASH FOR WINNINGS. THIS SHOULD BE BALANCE OF MY OVERALL BTC ACCOUNT.
                                min_reel_loop:2,          //NUMBER OF REEL LOOPS BEFORE SLOT STOPS  
                                reel_delay: 6,            //NUMBER OF FRAMES TO DELAY THE REELS THAT START AFTER THE FIRST ONE
                                time_show_win:2000,       //DURATION IN MILLISECONDS OF THE WINNING COMBO SHOWING
                                time_show_all_wins: 2000, //DURATION IN MILLISECONDS OF ALL WINNING COMBO
                                money:<?php echo $btcbalance;?> ,               //STARING CREDIT FOR THE USER - THIS IS GOING TO BE AN ECHO OF USER ADDRESS BALANCE.. So 'getbalance of addressofsessionidvariable'
                                ad_show_counter:3
```

Answer (score 0):

you are echoing the balance at the time of page load, are you sure it will be same after your page loaded.

it's the constant value then try this-

```
money:'<?php echo $btcbalance;?>'
```